# Have any script to lazy load all offscreen image?

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed

My site has over 200 pages, I don't want to fix each page manually.

I would like to lazy load only images that on offscreen.

Have any script can be done automatically?

Best regards,

Comment: I'd go with https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes
its a vanilla js (jquery free) library which does excactly that.